# Dangers of using computers as wireless access points?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, connection-sharing

My workplace's wifi setup isn't the best - each of our two floors only has one access point. Naturally, the wifi has a tendency to get really slow (I've seen it at 300 Kb/s), so we've given every cubicle an Ethernet cable, but everyone wants reliable wifi.

Earlier today I ran an experiment and found that connecting my phone to my laptop with [Ethernet -> wifi sharing](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-your-mac-into-wi-fi-hotspot-share-your-wired-connection-3653936/) is dozens of times faster than connecting to the company wifi directly, so: *Why couldn’t we just set up several computers to create their own networks with the company network’s name/password, basically giving us several more access points?*

I feel like there has to be something wrong with this idea because it’s not already a mainstream practice, I’m just not sure what it is. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I'm not certain that your IT department would be thrilled about this.

Comment: `giving us several more access points?` Or you could spend some money on more access points which are cheaper then laptops, use less power, and are easier to manage, easier to mount in a location to provide good signal, won't be running a consumer OS like a typical laptop and so on.  Your suggestion isn't mainstream, because it doesn't make any sense from a cost perspective.

Comment: @EEAA We don't really have an IT department, just a customer support team who also does the occasional desktop support work.

Comment: ...and wouldn't involve an extra NAT.

Comment: @Zoredache But we already have plenty of laptops, so we'd be spending no money whatsoever.

Comment: There are good ways to solve this problem. Using wifi sharing from desktop machines is not one of them. If you are budget-constrained, Ubiquiti has a decent line of centrally-managed APs that can be had for ~$100US each, which is ridiculously cheap.

Comment: `so we'd be spending no money whatsoever.` - time (person-hours) is money, more or less.  You would be spending a lot of a persons salary to setup and manage a mess.

Comment: "so we'd be spending no money whatsoever." - I didn't know electricity was free where you live. Mind tell us where so I can move to this paradise?

Answer (score 6):

No. No. No.

To list just a few things (of the dozens) that are horrible about this proposal:

- Traffic behind each workstation would be NATted, making auditing impossible. Also, likely breaking certain types of network traffic.
- Workstations/laptops would need to be left on 24x7
- Central management is impossible. Centralized management is crucial for a secure, well-performing wifi deployment
- All traffic passing through the workstation would be able to be inspected and MITM'd. This is a significant security issue.
- Network performance of the workstations is now beholden to how many wireless clients are connected
- You have no visibility into which AP people are connected to, making troubleshooting impossible

I could go on for about 10 more bullets. In short, it would be a management, support, and security nightmare. Just don't do it.

As mentioned above, Ubiquiti has [some really inexpensive](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-lite/) APs that perform well and are centrally-managed.

Comment: Lots of relevant points, but I feel you missed the most important. More APs fighting over the same frequencies is by no means guaranteed to improve performance.